# Qt Multi-Threading

Tags: c++, qt

I am Trying to read data from text files and save tokens in SQLite databae running on windows
The Files size is about 300MB , the thing is that I am not using threads yet , the application collapses and stuck with "not responding" message 
here is my code

```
QDir dir(ui->lineEdit->text());
if(dir.exists() && ui->lineEdit->text()!=""){
    CreateTables();

    dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    dir.setSorting(QDir::Size | QDir::Reversed);

    QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)  {
        QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
        QFile file(ui->lineEdit->text()+"/"+ fileInfo.fileName());

        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
            QSqlQuery qrry;
            qrry.prepare( "INSERT INTO documents (path) VALUES ('"+ui->lineEdit->text()+"/"+ fileInfo.fileName()+"')" );
            qrry.exec();

            QString line;
            QTextStream in(&file);
            int lineCount=0;
            while (!in.atEnd()) {

                line = in.readLine();
                lineCount++;
                QRegExp rx("(\\ |\\,|\\.|\\:|\\t)"); 
                QStringList line_tokens = line.split(rx);

                for(int i=0;i<line_tokens.length();i++){
                    if(line_tokens[i].length()>3){
                        QSqlQuery qry;
                        qry.prepare( "INSERT INTO tokens (token,path,line) VALUES ('"+line_tokens[i]+"', '"+ui->lineEdit->text()+"/"+ fileInfo.fileName()+"','"+QString::number(lineCount)+"')" );
                        qry.exec();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            QMessageBox::information(this,"File Read Error","Couldn't Open File, Please Make Sure That This File Is Accessable And Readable !");
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
else{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,"Directory choosen is Not Valid","Please Make Sure That You Have Choosen A Valid Directory!");
}
```

it works for a small file sizes but when it comes to huge amount of data it becomes gives the "not responding" message

will threads save the application from being collapsed ?? 
and how may I implements threads to do this job for more thant 20 files of 15 MB each

Comment: Your code is messed up. I have tried to format it, but it appears that some parts are missing, and it won't even format.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to clarify what you mean by "collapses"? And, describe the error or perfomance issue in more detail...

Comment: this is the part that do the files parsing , no need to know the rest

Comment: @AymanJitan At least post some properly formatted code which could compile.

Comment: @Bart I am sorry , This is the full code

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I just edited the post , you can look at it

Comment: Why don't you run it through a debugger to see if you can find the issue? Then, if you're still having trouble, post back with additional questions. Others will do so for you, but I generally refuse to answer very general "please debug my code for me" type of questions.

Comment: @SanJacinto , I think you couldn't understand my question
it works for a small file sizes but when it comes to huge amount of data it becomes gives the "not responding" message

Comment: Does the 'not responding' message go away if you wait for long enough like for minutes? If it's just the process than it should ultimately go away. The issue than will easily be fixed by threads.

Comment: @zadane yes it goes away but it takes alogn time , 
Do you have any ideas how to implement the thread on my code , just ideas I'll do the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First*, you can simply... wait until it process all the data. If you should run this program only once, it is ok.

Then, you should not generate such stream of requests to database. It is much better to run one single big insertion, than a lot of small. You can use `batch` execution.

Then, it's probably no reason of trying to parallel writing to Db. I think, it's smart enough to manage writing efficiently.

But it worth paralleling parsing. The best solution here is to use `QtConcurrent` framework. It is made exactly for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is ideal situation where you would want to use threads. The threads will do all the work in the background and while it will still take its time to process the data, your GUI will not appear hanged or not responding.

I don't fully understand your application but you could either write a single thread which does all this processor intensive work or even two threads one of reading file and the other for database but two threads require greater effort to implement. I will suggest stick with one thread first as it's simpler.

You definitely want to use threads here, it will solve your application not responding message which often people interpret as 'it collapsed' or 'hanged' while the application main thread is just too busy depriving GUI to function properly.